# Creating layout in Python for QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layouts

How can I create a layout and import it into .jpg or .png format?
This code:

```
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    from qgis.core import *
    from qgis.gui import *
    # create image
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    img = QImage(QSize(800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
    color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
    img.fill(color.rgb())
    # create painter
    p = QPainter()
    p.begin(img)
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    render = QgsMapRenderer()
    # set layer set
    lst = [layer.id()] # add ID of every layer
    render.setLayerSet(lst)
    # set extent
    rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())
    rect.scale(1.1)
    render.setExtent(rect)
    # set output size
    render.setOutputSize(img.size(), img.logicalDpiX())
    # do the rendering
    render.render(p)
    p.end()
  # save image
    img.save("C:/project_qgis/render.png","png")
```

give me:

[image]

Comment: Only replace img.save("C:/project_qgis/render.png","png") with img.save("C://project_qgis//render.png","png")